# "Rails way" to apply javascript to link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some plain HTML that provides some functionality when a link is clicked. I want to clean this up so that it is handled in a way that conforms to Ruby/Rails coding style. I tried messing with `link_to` helpers but couldn't figure out a clean way to handle this situation.

```
<p>...or <a id="set_current_location" href="#">Use Current Location</a></p>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#set_current_location').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '<%= set_location_path %>',
              data: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
              },
              async: false
            });
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Update: I've actually moved the javascript into a coffeescript file, so that's not really my question. I'm really just wondering if this looks like a rails-like way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "rails way" would be to leave your javascript out of your view, using unobtrusive javascript in a separate file. At first glance, your code is fine - just move your "script" stuff into a .js file.

Comment: He is not asking where to orgqanize the files, but the rails way to generate the link

Comment: He's asking for the Rails way to do it. This answer is correct. Write your JS code in a separate asset JS file that unobstrusively listens to events. Done.

Comment: actually I've already moved the code into a .coffee file ;). I guess I'm really asking if my approach is a commonly used technique or if there is a more rails-like approach

Answer (score 1):

The only way which I can think of is passing the rails generated path (url) when calling this function. I have used `$(this).attr("href")`. create an attribute `href` in the element. this href attribute will have the link generated by rails.

The js.erb will not have actionview methods

```
$(function(){
    $('#set_current_location').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
              },
              async: false
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: I like how this uses the `href` so that the original link could potentially still work. However, in this case, the link isn't useful without javascript, so I am hiding it if javascript is not available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think you are..

```
<%= link_to "Use Current Location", "#", id: :set_current_location %>
```

That'll do it.